# Argument missing with no default

Tags: r, shiny

My app was running before, but after I tried to add icons to the tab panels in the navbarpage, the app would not run anymore. I have checked every possible syntax problem, and I just can't pinpoint where the problem lies. Here is my code:

```
if(interactive()){
library(shiny)
library(shinycustomloader)
library(shinythemes)
library(SentimentAnalysis)
library(textclean)
library(reactable)
library(tm)  

ui<-navbarPage(strong("Mavis Analytic"),theme=shinytheme("cerulean"),
               windowTitle="Mavis Analytic",fluid=TRUE,inverse=FALSE,
               tabPanel(strong("Opinion Miner"),icon=icon("table"),
                          sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(width=3,
                          img(src="logo.jpg",height=130,width=150),
                          h4(strong("Enter your texts in these fields")),
                          actionButton("clear","Clear Fields"),br(),br(),
                          textAreaInput("text","Text Field 1",value="It is a beautiful day"),
                          textAreaInput("texts","Text Field 2",value="I am happy to be here"),
                          textAreaInput("word","Text Field 3",value="Let's have some fun"),
                          textAreaInput("words","Text Field 4",value="It has been a bad outing"),
                          textAreaInput("wordy","Text Field 5",value="I dislike clowns"),
                          actionButton("run","Run Analysis"),br(),br(),h5(strong("The number of words entered into each text field:")),tableOutput("count"),tableOutput("freq")),
                          mainPanel(h4("The Opinion Miner is a tool for conducting sentiment analysis. It is useful for generating insights from product reviews as well as social media posts."),withLoader(reactableOutput("table"),loader="dnaspin"),downloadButton("download",strong("Download Table")),
                                    selectInput("choice","Select Sentiment Score to Plot",choices=c("QDAP","LoughranM","HarvardIV")),selectInput("color","Select Color",choices=c("Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple")),
                                    withLoader(plotOutput("plot",height=400,width=400),loader="dnaspin"),withLoader(plotOutput("graph",height=400,width=400),loader="dnaspin")))),

               tabPanel(strong("Financial Ratios Calculator"),icon=icon("table")),
               tabPanel(strong("Send Us Your Feedback")),
               navbarMenu(strong("More"),
               tabPanel(strong("Graphs and Charts")),
               tabPanel(strong("Tables"))),

)
server<-function(input,output,session){

      observeEvent(input$clear,{
      updateTextAreaInput(session,"text",value="",placeholder="Enter new text")
      updateTextAreaInput(session,"texts",value="",placeholder="Enter new text")
      updateTextAreaInput(session,"word",value="",placeholder="Enter new text")
      updateTextAreaInput(session,"words",value="",placeholder="Enter new text")
      updateTextAreaInput(session,"wordy",value="",placeholder="Enter new text")

    })

  doc<-reactive({c(input$text,
                   input$texts,
                   input$word,
                   input$words,
                   input$wordy)})
  many<-reactive({termFreq(paste(
                          input$text,
                          input$texts,
                          input$word,
                          input$words,
                          input$wordy
  ))})
  Analyze<-reactive({
    round(analyzeSentiment(
      replace_symbol(
        replace_number(
          replace_ordinal(
            doc())))),1)})
  isolate_Analyze<-isolate(Analyze())
  QDAP<-isolate_Analyze$SentimentQDAP
  LoughranM<-isolate_Analyze$SentimentLM
  HarvardIV<-isolate_Analyze$SentimentGI

  word.count<-reactive({countWords(doc(),removeStopwords=FALSE)})

  tables<-reactive({
    data.frame(QDAP,LoughranM,HarvardIV)
  })
  isolate.tables<-isolate(tables())
  data<-reactive({switch(input$choice,
                         "QDAP"=isolate.tables$QDAP,
                         "LoughranM"=isolate.tables$LoughranM,
                         "HarvardIV"=isolate.tables$HarvardIV)})


  output$download<-downloadHandler(
    filename=function(){
      paste("table",".csv",sep="")
    },
    content=function(file){
      write.csv(tables(),file)
    }
  )
  output$table<-renderReactable({
      input$run
      isolate(reactable(tables(),searchable=TRUE,bordered=TRUE,defaultColDef=colDef(
      align="center",
      headerStyle=list(background="#5dade2"),
      style=function(value){
        if(value>0){color<-"#27ae60"}
        else if(value<0){color<-"#e74c3c"}
        else{color<-"#5dade2"}
        list(color=color,fontWeight="bold")
      }),
      highlight=TRUE,outlined=TRUE,striped=TRUE,filterable=FALSE,compact=TRUE,onClick="select")
      )
  })

  output$count<-renderTable({
        input$run
        isolate(data.frame(word.count()))
       })

  output$freq<-renderTable({
        input$run
        isolate(as.matrix(many()))
      })

  output$plot<-renderPlot({

    color<-switch(input$color,
                  "Blue"="#5dade2",
                  "Red"="#e74c3c",
                  "Green"="#1abc9c",
                  "Yellow"="#f7dc6f",
                  "Purple"="#a569bd")

    barplot(data(),col=color,border="white",xlab="Texts",ylab="Sentiment Scores",main="Bar Plot of Sentiment Scores")

  })
  output$graph<-renderPlot({


            plotSentiment(data())
      })



}
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Whenever I run the app, I get the error message: "Error in navbarPage: argument is missing, with no default".

Comment: you have an extra comma. Remove the comma after `tabPanel(strong("Tables")))`

Comment: Thank you very much. God bless you!